# 8086: Array is not getting values from a register

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

```
.data?
  binary_1 db 8 dup(?)    ; adjust '8' to the value you need
.code
  mov ax,temp 
  mov cx,8
  mov bx,02h 
  mov di,7
loop_b: 
  mov dx,0h
  div bx      
  mov [binary_1+di] , dl
  dec di  
  loop loop_b
```

This code is to convert the decimal value in `temp` to binary. The logic seems correct, but the `mov` instruction is not working. The value of `binary_1` is always zero and `dl` contains the remainder of the division. I tried moving the value in `dl` to a variable and it worked, but it is not working on the `binary_1` array.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am using emu8086.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. You've left out some important information, like what the value of `temp` is, how `binary_1` is declared, and how you've verified that the contents of the array are all zeroes.

Comment: And as always, there's no reason to use `div` to divide by 2. A simple right-shift will do.

Comment: the array is defined as :  binary_1 db ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?  ...... and i did single step simulations and checked that the value is 0 in the array , and temp is equal to 22

Comment: Well, I'm using NASM and DOSBox, and I can't reproduce that. If I print the contents of the array using `int 21h/ah=02h` I get `00010110`.

Comment: i printed the value and it is correct , but the value on the simulator keeps showing zeros

Comment: Are you sure that the `DS` segment register points at *.data?*

Comment: Mov ax, @data
Mov ds, ax  ........ i have this at the beginning of the code